# How to insert a code snippet into a string in MSVS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, code-snippets

I want to insert a code snippet from a code snippet library in Visual Studio into a string instead of a code editor window using C#. Into a code editor window a snippet is inserted like this:

```
IVsTextLines textLines;
m_vsTextView.GetBuffer(out textLines);
IVsExpansion bufferExpansion = (IVsExpansion)textLines;
bufferExpansion.InsertNamedExpansion(...);
```

The problem is that I can't find out how to get an IVsExpansion (or IVsTextLines) compatible text buffer from a anything but a text editor window. The code like this:

```
string s = "";
IVsExpansion bufferExpansion = (IVsExpansion)s;
```

doesn't work because string is not convertible to IVsExpansion. Can someone advise how to create a text buffer with which the IVsExpansion interface can be connected?

Comment: What object are you starting with?  Eventually you need an `IVsTextLines` or `ITextBuffer` (recommend the latter) in order to insert into Visual Studio.  You have to start with a `DTE.Window`, file, etc ...  where is your code starting from?

Comment: @JaredPar - I'm trying to implement a custom VSPackage for working with snippets. And I want to insert a snippet into a simple text box in a Windows Form (dialog box). I couldn't find out how to use a text box control instead of VS editor code window for working with IVsExpansion.